# How works this calculation?

Tags: lua, calculation, pan, calc

I am working with dmx that gives me values from 0 to 255 and the motor moves from -270 to 270.
I need the calculation that this program uses.

(i am using lua)

[Img 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yx0VV.png)

[Img 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qoFT.png)

[Img 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9nkR.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luke100000 gave the following formulas:
1- dmx / 255 * 540 - 270 = motor
2- motor (x) = 9/138176 x ^ 2 + 290313/138176 x - 270

the first if I get a value of 255 gives me 270
the second if I get a value of 255 it gives me 265.7724569868085

so the first would be the most accurate.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert of your technology, but from your images, it seems that you have a linear function from [0, 255] -> [-270, 270]

So I guess the value 129 gives you a motor value of 2,1 approximately.

I let you check this and process the other values accordingly. If needed, draw a function graph to see the shape of your function.

Comment: 129 = 3
127 = -1

Comment: `dmx / 255 * 540 - 270 = motor` would be the linear mapping. However, 128 is not 0, so it's not completely linear (that's why usually 127 is the center when using a byte). By solving a function of second degree going through our 3 points we get something like `motor(x) = 9 / 138176 x^2 + 290313 / 138176 x - 270`